# Returning a struct and passing a struct to functions

Tags: c

I am trying to return a struct which is defined as below:

```
EXAMPLE.C
struct test
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
struct test t1,t2;
```

I don't even have to explain the function, because I am getting error while declaring the function in the header file.

```
EXAMPLE.H
test calculate(int percent,int distance);
int modify(struct test x1);
```

So I will return the struct `t1` in the function `calculate` and i will pass the struct `t2` into the function `modify`. I am not sure what am I doing wrong, but I am getting syntax error

Comment: Did you even READ the error? I really takes less time than posting a question. So compilers also show messages like *Did you mean ...*.

Comment: How does `EXAMPLE.H` know what `test` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your struct type is called `struct test`. Not just `test`, but `struct test`. Two words. You used the proper type name in your `modify` function. You used the proper type name in the declaration of `t1` and `t2`. Why did you suddenly shorten it to a mere `test` in case of `calculate`?

Secondly, it appears that you are trying to use a yet-undeclared struct type in your function declarations, since the functions are declared in `.h` file and struct type is declared in `.c` file. Something like this can be done properly, but this is generally not a good idea (unless you are trying to implement an opaque type). And most likely this is not what you are trying to do. So, why are you declaring your struct type in `.c` file? A better idea would be to declare it in `.h` file as well, above your functions.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that care should be taken in understanding the difference between a function *declaration* and the function *definition*. (it may not be so obviously apparent to new C programmers)

Comment: I know the difference between declaration & definition. it was the declaration in the .h file. But I was in wrong assumption that I can declare the struct in .c file. I was wrong. and also missing "struct". Thank you!